using Multiple IFs on Google sheets
I am trying to do addition on a cell based on values in different cell
I have 2 Columns: Value  Date and Trade Date , there are multiple rows which will have value
I need a logic where, if Trade Date = Value date (which can be in multiple rows) then sum up all the values and show in one column.
If trade Date not equal to value date then sum all and display in different column
Here is sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1osNd-iS5ZkKzrX6cyVlp2z1VN4GV9LI4kctZ2jQ-N6k/edit?usp=sharing
